# Dataframe checking if the string ends with a number and remove

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a column foo in a dataframe df, which looks like:

```
0            abc1
1             def
2           g3sse1
3           f32asd
```

I do not want the number at the end, if there is any.

```
0             abc
1             def
2            g3sse
3           f32asd
```

Like this.

The best I can do is:

```
df.foo[df['foo'].str[-1].str.isdigit()] = df['foo'].str[:-1]
```

This solves the problem, but... I am curious if there is more elegant way to do this. I guess regex won't make it look any better, but I appreciate any ideas!

Comment: What happens if there is more than one number at the end of an entry?

Comment: @RichardKYu That does not happen in this dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your input only contains trailing numbers, and in this case you don't want to use regular expressions, you can also use [`rstrip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rstrip.asp) and python's [`string`](https://www.journaldev.com/23788/python-string-module) module:

```
import string
df['foo_refined'] = df['foo'].str.rstrip(string.digits)

      foo foo_refined
0    abc1         abc
1     def         def
2  g3sse1       g3sse
3  f32asd      f32asd
```

---

```
a = '12a'
>>> a.rstrip(string.digits)
'12a'

b = '12a2'
>>> b.rstrip(string.digits)
'12a'

c = '12a12x'
>>> c.rstrip(string.digits)
'12a12x'

d = '123'
>>> d.rstrip(string.digits)
''
```

And a reference to [`lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html), which as expected would strip any digits from the start not from the end if used in this context.

Comment: best one yet, assuming OP wants to strip all trailing digits

Comment: I have never in my dream thought about string module. Really appreciate your solution!

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is fine. An alternative is:

```
df['foo_new'] = df['foo'].str.extract('(.*)\d$').fillna(df['foo'])
```

Comment: Wow ok, regex does make it look way better than my solution. Thanks for your brilliant idea~

Comment: Not sure why you opted for "extract & compensate" instead of "remove", i.e., `df[col].str.replace(r"\d*$", "")`. Uninteresting.

Comment: @Neither no particular reason other than not thinking of `str.replace` with regex.